# Converting a pandas dataframe column values from string to float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dtype

I have a data frame with columns A, B, and C as follows:

df:

```
A    B    C

1990 1  1,00,000
2000 2  2,00,000
2001 3  3,00,000
```

I want to convert the column C from object to float. For that, I run the following command:

`df["C"].astype(float)`

It gives the error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,00,000'
```

How do I convert the column to float or int?

Comment: Its just me or the commas placed on the wrong place..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df["C"].str.replace(",", "").astype(float)
```